# Tweet the score of HTML5 game without possible tampered values

Tags: html, twitter

I'm developing a game in HTML5 (WIP) and came with this hard situation... the game is very simple, you play, you lose or win, and you have a score. Then, the game has the option to share your score, but... how to avoid tampered values?

All I've got so far is a share button of Twitter in my game, when you click it, appears a modal window of Twitter saying: "I've scored X points in this game!" **but that text is editable**, that means... everyone can change the points and write some tampered values.

Is there a way to Tweet this status without being able to cheat the game score? Maybe there's a way to directly tweet the score disabling the modal window of Twitter that allows to edit the text.

Any solution to this? if not, what piece of advice can you give me to post unaltered scores on social media? (preferably Twitter)

Your help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In short, **no**.

You **could** prevent the modal from allowing the user to enter data, which would stop most manipulation. However, there is **no** way to prevent users from tampering with their scores in order to falsify them, even after the score is submitted.

Tools such as the [**Tamper Data**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) addon for Firefox allow people to 'freeze' score submission, and manipulate values as they're being `POST`ed to the server. Unfortunately, you **cannot** prevent users from falsifying their scores in this way.

The best you can do is obfuscate your scoring system, making it difficult for people to understand how it works. That won't necessarily *prevent* them from manipulating their scores, but it would make it more difficult to do so.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

Once suggestions is, you can put post scores as an image which can be base-64 data. Here's the Twitter API for uploading base-64 media data,

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/media/upload

You can generate score images using HTML5 Canvas and convert it into base-64 image data using `canvas.toDataURL()` and pass it to twitter API

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe there's a way to directly tweet the score disabling the modal window of Twitter that allows to edit the text.

Yes, you will need to have the player sign in to your app using Twitter. Once done, your app can Tweet on the player's behalf using the API.

Comment: Please tell me more! :)